# Sum of numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, sum

```
def find_least_numbers_to_exceed_target(numbers, target):
    dp = [float(-1)] * (target + 1)
    dp[0] = 0    for num in numbers:
        for i in range(target, num - 1, -1):
            dp[i] = min(dp[i], dp[i - num] + 1)

    return dp[target]

numbers = [70, 86, 19]
initial = 20
target = 100 - initial


result = find_least_numbers_to_exceed_target(numbers, target)
print(f"The least number of elements needed to achieve {target} or exceed it is {result}")
```

The code above is finding the least number to achieve or exceed the target number. The initial number is 20 so the program can only add numbers that are **less than** 20 which is 19 in the list. Then, it will become 39, but no other number can be added to 39 because no number is **less than** 39 now. So the final answer would be -1 because no solution.

Another example
[4,3,4,1,2]

Initial = 3

Target = 10

For this data, 1 and 2 are **less than** 3, so 1+3=4, then 4+3=7, then 7+4=11. So the final answer is 3

Note that the number in the list can only be used one time.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

The code you provided is many problem in syntax in a python , but there's a small issue in the initialization of the `dp` list, and you need to handle the case where it's not possible to achieve the target.

Update code:

```py
def find_least_numbers_to_exceed_target(numbers, initial, target):
    dp = [float("inf")] * (target + 1)
    dp[0] = 0

    for num in numbers:
        for i in range(target, num - 1, -1):
            dp[i] = min(dp[i], dp[i - num] + 1)

    if dp[target] == float("inf"):
        return -1

    return dp[target]


numbers =[70, 86, 19]
initial = 20
target = 100 - initial

result = find_least_numbers_to_exceed_target(numbers, initial, target)
print(f"The least number of elements needed to achieve {target} or exceed it is {result}")
```

**Outputs:**

```
The least number of elements needed to achieve 80 or exceed it is -1
```

Comment: uh, [10 ,16 ,19 ,5, 4] this is another input. The output should be 4, but when i run the code given, the output it -1

Comment: @Zoey what is the initial and target?

Comment: sorry, the initial is 5 and the target is 38

Comment: @Zoey Correct answer is 2 not 4 ?

Comment: 5+4=9, then 9+5= 14, then 14+19=33, then 33+10,=43

Comment: Even 2 is correct, the given code shows -1 as the output

Comment: @Zoey Sorry about the error check my code

Comment: uh, the output of the code is 3, but still wrong, it should be 4

Comment: @Zoey Perhaps you have not experienced that it gives the desired result

Comment: So it means that your code got an error, otherwise it should be alright for all the inputs

Comment: @Zoey my code alright for all the inputs